# Sum data and merge results by updating table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following data:

Table1

| UniqueKey | Text A | Text B | Value 1 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Key1 | ABC | ABC | 2 | 3 |
| Key2 | DEF | GHI | 3 | 4 |
| Key3 | STE | GGE | 5 | 5 |
| Key2 | DEF | GHI | 3 | 4 |
| Key2 | DEF | GHI | 5 | 7 |
| Key1 | ABC | ABC | 3 | 7 |

Using the key UniqueKey I want to add the values in the columns Value 1 and Values 2 so that each Unique Key exists only once in my table.

The Table1 should then look like this:

| UniqueKey | Text A | Text B | Value 1 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Key1 | ABC | ABC | 5 | 10 |
| Key2 | DEF | GHI | 11 | 15 |
| Key3 | STE | GGE | 5 | 5 |

I have already made the following considerations. I can use the group by and sum command to add the columns as desired.
I have trouble saving these changes in the table and deleting the redundant columns. So far I have only used the merge command on two different tables.

```sql
SELECT UniqueKey, SUM(Value1) Value1, SUM(Value2) Value2
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY UniqueKey
```

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new table with the current query

```
SELECT [UniqueKey], [Text A], [Text B], SUM([Value 1]) AS Value1, SUM([Value 2]) AS Value2
  INTO Table2
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY [UniqueKey], [Text A], [Text B]
```

drop the original source

```
DROP TABLE Table1
```

rename new one to the original

```
sp_rename 'Table2', 'Table1'
```

and add a primary key on *UniqueKey* column to enforce uniqueness as the last step

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD PRIMARY KEY (UniqueKey);
```

Comment: If they plan to drop the table, they will need to be sure that they've duplicated any foreign keys and indexes that `Table1` has, on `Table2`. They may also need to check for views built over `Table1`.

Comment: Also, you have omitted columns `Text A` and `Text B` in the result, which are not in the OP's query, but are in their proposed table structure.

Comment: thanks @AnnL. , didn't notice the extra columns then.

Comment: Need to be able see the whole scenario for the first case you've mentioned @AnnL.

Comment: Agreed! I only added the comment for the OP's benefit: if they are modifying the def. of `Table1` they have a couple of other things they need to check for.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to group by the columns the other 2 columns Text A and Text B.

```
SELECT UniqueKey, [Text A], [Text B], SUM([Value 1]) AS Val1, SUM([Value 2]) AS Val2
FROM Table1
GROUP BY UniqueKey, [Text A], [Text B]
```

If you want to get this data into Table1, you can save the result of the query above in a temp table, delete the data in Table1, then re-insert the data from the temp table into Table1.

```
-- Check if you have a temp table #Table1, if so drop it
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table1') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Table1
END 
GO

-- Save the data into temp table #Table1
SELECT UniqueKey, [Text A], [Text B], SUM([Value 1]) AS Val1, SUM([Value 2]) AS Val2 INTO #Table1
FROM Table1
GROUP BY UniqueKey, [Text A], [Text B]
GO

-- Delete the data in Table1
DELETE FROM Table1
GO

-- Re-insert the data from the temp table #Table1 into Table1
INSERT INTO Table1 (UniqueKey, [Text A], [Text B], [Value 1], [Value 2])
SELECT UniqueKey, [Text A], [Text B], [Value 1], [Value 2]
FROM #Table1
GO
```

Comment: Note that if the user wants to have `Table1` enforce uniqueness, they will have to modify the definition of the table to include either a Primary Key constraint, or a unique index.

Comment: I am trying to understand the code. How does #Table1 affect my SQL DB. Is it a temporary table or do I create a new table with it. After running the query I do not see the table in the database. However, I get the error message "There is already an object named '#Table1' in the database." when I run the query several times in a row. @Dragon

Comment: @tommy74 the INTO command creates a new table and when there is a # at the front of the name, it creates a temp table. So when you ran it again, it detected there was a temp table already created. The temp table would only exist in that session, so if you closed the query window, it would remove the temp table. However, I've modified the query to check if that temp table exists in the session and if so, then drop it and then it gets recreated straight after.